# Using seterror for edittext validation in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to validate a edittext using the seterror method.I am using the focus changed listener for checking whether the edittext has length of zero or not.But when i try to type into the required edittext, i cannot type into it and the text is being typed into the second one.Please help!!

The code:

```
package com.example.usernamevalidation;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText txtusername,txtpassword;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtusername=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtusername);
        txtpassword=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtpassword);
        txtusername.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(!hasFocus)
                {
                    if(txtusername.getText().toString().length()==0)
                    {
                        txtusername.requestFocus();
                        txtusername.setError("Username cannot be left blank");
                    }
                }
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

The xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="300px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtusername"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="300px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtpassword"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Remove this line :  txtusername.requestFocus();
```

Comment: If i do that the message is not being shown.Only the exclamation is being shown.

Comment: Also is the setonfocuschange listener the right choice.I want to check when i leave the edittext.

Comment: but this line says that if current focus o\not there than it focus that edittext show you cant write in this so

Comment: than maintain the condition for that request focus

Answer (score 0):

Use a `TextWatcher` and in its `onTextChanged()` check whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

it is very simple you have create more your code more complex let try this code Use [TextUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html)  `TextUtils.isEmpty`-Returns true if the string is null or 0-length.

```
EditText txtusername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtusername);
EditText txtpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtpassword);

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(txtusername.getText().toString())){
        txtusername.setError("Username cannot be left blank");
        txtusername.requestFocus();
    }
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(txtpassword.getText().toString())){
        txtpassword.setError("password cannot be left blank");
        txtpassword.requestFocus();
    }

   //do logging process
```

Comment: This works.But the error i shown right from the beginning.I want the error to be shown only when i ignore the first edittext and go to the second one.